# How do you design a regression experiment with many variables but samples are expensive?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, experiment-design

I want to design an experiment to see which factors affect production quality. Quality can either be a binary response like "good" or "bad" or a quantitative value like noise level.

There are 10 factors/attributes I'm interested in, and each factor can take on 4 values. Due to cost, I can only make 500 samples of product while varying the attributes in any way I like. This means there cannot be a sample for each unique combination of attributes. How big of a concern is this?

After getting the data, I plan to run a regression to see which factors are significant. I might also try step wise regression or do model selection using F tests. Are these valid approaches?

A few question: 
1. Given the number of attributes, which is an "ideal" minimum number of samples to get a decent model, if samples are cheap? Does it matter if the attributes are numeric or categorical (in this case)?

2. What if the response are multi-class? For example, there might be different failure modes of "bad" and I'd like to use those as response. Since logistic regression is usually not used for multi-class classification, what would be a better model for this case?

Comment: Sounds like a [fractional factorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_factorial_design) may be of interest to you. I usually see these done where the factors can take on only two values, usually something like "low" and "high". It might make your life easier if you're able to group the four levels of your factors into two "composite" levels. But this won't work unless there's some natural ordering of those levels. There might be software out there that generates four-level fractional designs out there, I'm not sure. This isn't a full answer but maybe someone else can expand.

Comment: One approach is to formulate your problem mathematically as an optimization problem. Designing an experiment to be optimal with respect to some criteria is called [optimal design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design).